# $gazebo fails to work after installing gazebo_ros_pkgs

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi. I'm in a dilemma. After [installing gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros), the 'rosrun/roslaunch gazebo_ros' commands work well and bring a Gazebo GUI.However when I run alone the command $gazebo in a terminal, nothing happens. Just nothing! Neither Gazebo GUI which is expected, nor warning/error information in the terminbal. I think something might go wrong with the environment variables or else, but I can't figure out. It's really awkward, for gazebo is there but not avaiable to me. I really need some help. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7384/$gazebo-fails-to-work-after-installing-gazebo_ros_pkgs/) by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please run:

export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

then run:

gazebo

---

Originally posted by [mudassar_ej](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1015/mudassar_ej/) with karma: 16 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on 2014-11-12**:
Thank you very much. Gazebo works! May I ask what does this environment variable LIBGLALWAYSOFTWARE mean and how does it affect the way Gazebo works?